# jQuery: get next instance of certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up a click function whereby when you click on a `h3` tag it will find all the next instances of `em` and `br` UNTIL the next instance of `h3` and show them. There's a jsFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/nm4a8njn/ and the markup below:
HTML:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_2">

<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>

<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>

<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>

<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>

<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.span_1_of_2 h3 {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.span_1_of_2 em {
    display: none;
}

.span_1_of_2 br {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".span_1_of_2 h3").click(function () {

        $(this).closest(".span_1_of_2").find("em").show();

    });        

});
```

But as you can see, when you click on a `h3` tag this is showing ALL instances of `em`, whereas I only want to target the `em` and `br` elements up until the next instance of `h3`. If this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) like

```
 $(this).nextUntil("h3").show();
```

This will get all next sibling elements **until** the provided selector

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".span_1_of_2 h3").click(function () {

        $(this).nextUntil("h3").show();
            
    });        

});
```

```css
.span_1_of_2 h3 {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.span_1_of_2 em {
    display: none;
}

.span_1_of_2 br {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
    
<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    
<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    
<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    
<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    
<h3>Title</h3>

    <br/><em>text goes here</em> 
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

AmmarCSE made it faster but anyways - here is a jQuery function `.nextUntil()` that will 1) fin all elements that is next to current element and 2) filter result set. Here's the working example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".span_1_of_2 h3").click(function () {

        $(this).nextUntil("h3","em").show();

    });        

});
```